# DevOps Organization disappeared after linking to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I created a number of organizations in Azure DevOps to experiment with.
They were all visible under existing Microsoft accounts (subscription accounts).
Then I created an Active Directory and linked one of the organizations to the newly-created directory.
After signoff and signon, the organization can no longer be found.
When I select the new directory in DevOps, there is only a default organization without my test project.
When I tried the same with another organization, this one also disappeared.
Where did my DevOps organization go?
And how can I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two ways to see if the organizations can be displayed.

1.Please try to access https://aex.dev.azure.com/ and change domain to see if your organization lists here.

[image]

2.Sign out completely from Azure DevOps by completing the following steps. Closing your browser might not sign you out completely. Sign in again and select your other identity:

1. Close all browsers, including browsers that aren't running Azure
   DevOps.
2. Open a private or incognito browsing session.
3. Go to this URL: https://aka.ms/vssignout.
   You see a message that says, "Sign out in progress." After you sign
   out, you're redirected to the Azure DevOps @dev.azure.microsoft.com
   webpage. If the sign-out page takes more than a minute to sign you out, close the browser and continue.
4. Sign in to Azure DevOps again. Select your other identity.

Comment: I already tried that all to no result.
Strange thing is that when I do the same to the Default Directory, it works...

Comment: It is happening with me too. I was using free version of the Azure DevOps and I had 5 users, later on i connected Azure Active Directory of my purchased subscription. As i added my organization disappered and my users who were registered in existing Azure DevOps are not able to login again, they are getting 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I previously logged in using "Personal" account, created organisation, and when logged out and logged in again selected "Work or Department" account, so I wasn't able to see my organisations because they were created and visible only on "Personal" account 'plan'.